# How to received a notification about removing user from FreeIPA?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, identity, freeipa

I am working on a Python application which uses FreeIPA to authenticate users. Once they got logged in, I assume there is a possiblity that one of users may be removed from FreeIPA when they are logged in in my application.

Is there a way to receive a notification from FreeIPA that the logged in user was removed from FreeIPA and therefore his session needs to be expired?